# Haskell HDBC-Sqlite3 always returns SqlByteString values

Tags: haskell, sqlite, hdbc

I am using HDBC sqlite3 haskell driver to access local sqlite3 database which

```
PRAGMA encoding
```

is

```
UTF-8
```

And as result, for example for

```
SELECT id, title FROM some_table
```

I'm always getting the result like this:

```
[[SqlByteString "1", SqlByteString "\210\129\123\211"], ... ]
```

That's weird! 
Yes, title contains 'national' symbols and yes, I'm sure that `id` has type of `INTEGER`.

So the questions are:

1. Why 1 unicode symbol are threated as 2 ascii-like symbols?
2. Why integer columns results bytestring values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is an untyped database, so the fields in your database don't really have a type at all. You should be converting them to a more Haskellish value by using `fromSql` or `safeFromSql` from [Database.HDBC.SqlValue](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC/2.2.6.1/doc/html/Database-HDBC-SqlValue.html).

Comment: But in the "Real World Haskell" book (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html) they using sqlite3 engine in chapter 21 and their examples do return correct (like SqlInt or SqlString) values. Why?

Comment: Their examples return `SqlString` and `SqlNull` but not `SqlInt` --- look more closely at what is returned (`SqlString "0"` etc). I presume the implementation has changed at some point to use `SqlByteString` instead of `SqlString`, I don't know why.